# EJB - EJBTransactionRolledbackException argument type mismatch - overloaded method

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, illegalstateexception, wildfly-8

I really need some help! By invoking an EJB that has method overloading, I'm having the following exception: *javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: argument type mismatch*

Interestingly, this happens randomly and only in this overloaded method. See the structure below:

```
// superclass
public abstract class GenericService<T> {

    public void update(T object) throws Exception {
        // some logic
    }

}

// subclass
@Stateless
public class TableService extends GenericService<Table> implements ITableService {

    @Override
    public void update(Table table) throws Exception {
        /*
         * some logic
         */

        // call super
        super.update(table);
    }
}
```

If I invoke *TableService.update* that contains the *super.update(table)* statement, the error occurs. But, if I remove ther *super.update(table)* statement from *TableService.update*, calling the DAO directly (skipping *super*), it works.

To make matters worse, it is not often that this happens too. Only when I restart jboss wildfly sometimes.

Apparently there is nothing wrong and should work fully containing the *super.update(table)* statement. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB proxy delivered by the container (JBOSS) passes the arguments for the respective method with type Object.
Thus, if there are overloading methods maybe the proxy can't resolve wich one to call

```
    @Stateless
public class TableService extends GenericService<Table> implements ITableService {

    @Override
    public void update(Table table) throws Exception {
        /*
         * some logic
         */

        // call super
        super.update(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(List<Table> table) throws Exception {
        /*
         * some logic
         */

        // call super
        super.update(table);
    }
}
```

`proxy.update(Object obj)...` argument type mismatch

Comment: I don't know why jboss is doing that but I think you are right. In this case, I just renamed the method. Thanks!